# Trying to use json data for a data source url in a google gadget

Tags: ajax, json, google-gadget

I'm trying to populate a google gadget with data retrieved in json format from a url. I've tried this with a couple of differet gadgets with no success. Here's a link to one of them:

http://adutlj344f2ceurc6kvvsnv146u2s48p.open.gmodules.com/ig/creator?synd=open&url=http%3A//www.google.com/ig/modules/column-chart.xml&pt=%26context%3Dd%26type%3Dgadgets%26synd%3Dig%26lang%3Den%26.lang%3Den%26country%3Dus%26.country%3Dus%26start%3D0%26num%3D1%26target%3Drqw%26objs%3D&sn=rqw&lang=en

Here's the link that I'm providing for the data source url:
http://www.pikefin.com/phpdev/ajaxsample/echodatasource.php

When I click on "Preview Data", eventually I get a message of "Request Timed out" in the preview window.

The json data should be value because I copied it from a google spreadsheet link which worked in the same gadget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what I changed (it might have been something on google's end) but the preview is working now.